# jquery: selecting xpath or converting xpath to css?

Tags: jquery, xpath

i need to select based on xpath , or convert xpath to css.

is there a plugin or built in function.

ex. `$('/html/body/div/a[4]').each ....`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with XPATH, I'm assuming that's finding every div on the page and then the 5th link for each of those divs?

Comment: I don't know if this is outdated or not, but this suggest jQuery can do that natively? 

http://dev.jquery.com/wiki/XPath?version=3

Comment: xpath support i believe was dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Not all xpath expressions are possible to translate to CSS-like selectors, or doesn't work efficiently. You can use the `:eq` selector to access elements by index, but it's recommended that you use the `eq` method for this instead. This would be equivalent of the xpath in your example:

```
$('html > body > div > a').eq(3).each( ...
```

Comment: You can also use `$('html > body > div > a:eq(4)').each( ...`

Comment: Note that `[4]` in Xpath corresponds with `eq(3)` in jQuery though! Xpath starts counting at 1, not 0.

Comment: @Blaise: Right, that is possible. However, the documentation recommends using the `eq` method for better performance in modern browsers: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ Good point about the index, I corrected the code in the answer.