# Tool to convert an XPath to a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, xpath, firebug

Firebug is able to display the xpath for any DOM element in the HTML view. I was wondering if there's a way to convert the xpath to a jQuery selector? (I prefer not to do this manually)

This will greatly save me time to find the correct selector for elements which don't have an id & are way deep in the DOM hierarchy. For example the fifth TD in the 20th TR

AFAIK, xpath support in jQuery is dropped so I can't use the xpath straight in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a 'copy css path' in Firebug when right-clicking an element. It can be used to create a selector.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking a general question abotu converting XPath to CSS selector, but I found this post [jquery: selecting xpath or converting xpath to css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619697/jquery-selecting-xpath-or-converting-xpath-to-css/1619714#1619714) which might be of help. It reccomends using "eq" method to select an element by index. So the fifth TD in the 20th TR would be

```
$('tr').eq(20).find('td').eq(5)
```

Comment: eq is 0-based: `$('tr').eq(19).find('td').eq(4)`

Comment: Also, depending on what's wanted, it may be better to use children() instead of find(). Basically the same but only travels a single level down the DOM tree.